# Use time range in Ad Insights of Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api, graph-api-explorer

I'm trying to obtain impressions of my ads between two dates

I'm using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with this path:

```
act_0123456789/ads?fields=insights{ad_id,ad_name,impressions}
```

I want to use 'time_range' attribute that we can find it in [Marketing API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/insights/) but I don't know the syntax. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can't comment on the approach you're using as I have not used it myself. However, here is an alternative approach which I have used with success:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_xyz/insights?level=<yourLevel>&fields=ad_id,ad_name,impressions&time_range[since]=2016-02-15&time_range[until]=2016-02-16&limit=25
```

where `<yourLevel>` can be one of: `ad`, `adset`, `campaign`

Also note that I am using straight up http requests in java which is why I show you the request itself. Hopefully you can extrapolate to your own solution.

Comment: meant to say: where <yourLevel> can be one of: ad, adset, campaign

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I have to specify 'insights?level=ad&fields[...]' instead of "/ads?fields=insights[...]"

Comment: Hi. is it possible to include hour and minutes?

Comment: Based on the API docs, I would say it only supports YYYY-MM-DD: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v2.9 (scroll down to time_range)

Answer (score 10):

Using the same endpoint  you've shown in your question

```
act_0123456789/ads?fields=insights{ad_id,ad_name,impressions}
```

The way to specify a time range would be

```
act_0123456789/ads?fields=insights.time_range({"since":"2017-08-07","until":"2017-08-14"}){ad_id,ad_name,impressions}
```

(of course, those two dates are provided just as an example)

Comment: Caveat: this answer was made when FB Api was in v2.4, I don't know if this still works for v3.3+ and I no longer use this API nor do I have access to any Page/Business to try it

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way of doing this is

```
act_0123456789?fields=ads{insights.time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}).time_increment(1){impressions}}
```

Remove  .time_increment(1) if you don't want day by day data

you can use {} for subfields like

```
 act_0123456789?fields=campaigns{ads{name,insights,adcreatives{image_url}}}
```

you can use . and () for parameters like; always make sure you use you use fields only after parameters like this order .(){}

```
act_0123456789?fields=campaigns.limit(1).time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}).time_increment(1).breakdowns(country){ads{name,insights.time_range({"since":"2019-03-03","until":"2019-03-03"}).time_increment(1).breakdowns(country),adcreatives{image_url}}}
```